# An interesting little 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I just tried to deploy to Heroku and got a 500 server error.

heroku logs:

```
Started GET "/" for ##.##.###.### at 2010-10-14 17:59:34 -0700  
  Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/index (2.3ms)
Completed   in 3ms

ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert nil into String):
5:   <meta charset="utf-8">
6:   <title>Hello</title>
7:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "global", "home", :cache => true %>  
app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

I then tried to start my local server in production mode:

```
c:\Sanj\ruby>rails server production  
Exiting  
C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:21:in `const_get': wrong constant name production (NameError)  
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:21:in `get'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `server'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:54:in `start'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

These issues seem highly related - do you know what the issue might be here?

Thanks very much!

---

Welcome Controller#index

```
def index 
  render :layout => "index"
end
```

Please tell me if I can supply any more information.

---

## Solution

Thanks to you guys for your answers. The problem was occurring because serve_static_assets was set to false in environments/production.rb. This enabled the system to find the CSS files that were apparently causing the 'nil'. The other change I tried was removing :cache => true from the stylesheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### serve_static_assets

The problem was occurring because serve_static_assets was set to `false` in environments/production.rb. Changing this enabled the system to find the CSS files that were the 'nil' it was trying to convert into a String. I also removed `:cache => true`, and in combination, this solved the Heroku deployment problem.

Answer (score 4):

They're not related. The error locally is because you're using the command incorrectly. Do:

```
rails server -e production
```

Comment: Thanks tfe. The most important error to me is the Heroku one because it is compromising the entire app from running. Do you know what the issue is there?

Comment: Sorry, can't say. Can you post the content of your layout and index view? Can you not render any other views, or is it just this one failing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if these 2 issues related...

First, would you please provide the code of your welcome controller? let's see what's going on there.

Second, your command not correct, please run:
rails server -e production

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've added in the welcome controller index action.

Comment: Hello @sscirrus, sorry but from current information, I can't tell what's wrong. But can you try to not render the index layout first, to isolate the problem. Or you can update the index layout view.