# Heroku app only rendering a few lines of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm using Heroku for the first time and am having a weird issue. I've pushed my app, but when I look at it, all I see is a few lines of irb code. Specifically:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css", :media => "screen and (min-width:481px)", :cache => true %> <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min", "jquery-ui.min", "jquery_ujs.min", "application.min" %> <%= csrf_meta_tag %> <%= yield :head %>
MyApp
<% if request.path == "/login" %>
<%= link_to "Sign Up", {:controller =>"users", :action => "new"}, {:id => 'login'} %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Log In", {:controller =>"sessions", :action => "new"}, {:id => 'login'} %>
<% end %>
```

I added a ticket to Heroku but am wondering if anyone here experienced something similar or had an idea as to what's happening. Here's what I see in my `heroku logs`:

```
2011-12-01T04:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1168280325920812315_38229020_2540660988792494126'
2011-12-01T04:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
2011-12-01T04:17:46+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-12-01T04:17:57+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e4c58ef by myemail@email.com
2011-12-01T04:17:57+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v14 created by myemail@email.com
2011-12-01T04:17:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
2011-12-01T04:17:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from bouncing to created
2011-12-01T04:17:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-12-01T04:18:00+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-12-01T04:18:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 43194`
2011-12-01T04:18:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2011-12-01 04:18:10] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2011-12-01T04:18:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2011-12-01 04:18:10] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2011-12-01T04:18:10+00:00 app[web.1]: [2011-12-01 04:18:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=43194
2011-12-01T04:18:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.0.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:43194
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.140.5.188 at 2011-12-01 04:18:13 +0000
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert nil into String):
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <!doctype html>
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <head>
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <title>MyApp</title>
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css", :media => "screen and (min-width:481px)", :cache => true %>
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min", "jquery-ui.min", "jquery_ujs.min", "application.min" %>
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1242101754664979387_45511700_1336663889607024244'
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered users/_dreamless_form.html.erb (16.9ms)
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (34.0ms)
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed   in 107ms
2011-12-01T04:18:13+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-journey-6792.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=335ms status=500 bytes=1013
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.140.5.188 at 2011-12-01 04:18:19 +0000
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert nil into String):
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <!doctype html>
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <head>
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <title>MyApp</title>
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css", :media => "screen and (min-width:481px)", :cache => true %>
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min", "jquery-ui.min", "jquery_ujs.min", "application.min" %>
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1242101754664979387_45511700_1336663889607024244'
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered users/_dreamless_form.html.erb (2.2ms)
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.0ms)
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed   in 7ms
2011-12-01T04:18:19+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-journey-6792.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=1013
2011-12-01T04:26:07+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-12-01T04:26:22+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v15 created by myemail@email.com
2011-12-01T04:26:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-12-01T04:26:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 18091`
2011-12-01T04:26:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-12-01T04:26:25+00:00 app[web.1]: [2011-12-01 04:26:25] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2011-12-01T04:26:25+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2011-12-01T04:26:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-12-01T04:26:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> Process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2011-12-01T04:26:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2011-12-01T04:26:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.140.5.188 at 2011-12-01 04:27:08 +0000
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert nil into String):
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>MyApp</title>
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css", :media => "screen and (min-width:481px)", :cache => true %>
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <!--[if IE]>
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css", :media => "all", :cache => true %><![endif]-->
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min", "jquery-ui.min", "jquery_ujs.min", "application.min" %>
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___172990433218769450_38326520_3796609424593531670'
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered users/_dreamless_form.html.erb (1.2ms)
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed   in 4ms
2011-12-01T04:27:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-journey-6792.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=48ms status=500 bytes=1013
2011-12-01T04:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.140.5.188 at 2011-12-01 04:30:27 +0000
2011-12-01T04:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-01T04:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert nil into String):
2011-12-01T04:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2011-12-01T04:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2011-12-01T04:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>MyApp</title>
2011-12-01T04:30:27+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css", :media => "screen and (min-width:481px)", :cache => true %>
2011-12-01T04:30:29+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-journey-6792.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=9ms status=500 bytes=1013
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938797/an-interesting-little-500-error

Comment: Wow, epic find. Removing :cache => true worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the responses in the question cited in the comments above ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938797/an-interesting-little-500-error)), removing :cache => true from my stylesheets did the trick.