# heroku db:push failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm getting an "Application Error" when I use heroku db:push (I'm using Taps 0.3.23).  I've seen some suggestions that this just happens sometimes on Heroku and then the problem goes away.  I've tried quite a few times over an 8 hour span, with the same result.  I think the following is the relevant Heroku log info:

```
2012-06-30T10:30:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2012-06-30T10:30:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-06-30T10:30:33+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-06-30 10:30:33] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-06-30T10:30:33+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-06-30T10:30:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-06-30T10:30:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-06-30T10:30:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-06-30T10:30:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to remove `:cache => true` from my stylesheets.

Relevant link : [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938797/an-interesting-little-500-error)